# In the Panama Canal, how are the lock gates kept water-tight (at the hinges, middle, and bottom)?

Tags: waterproofing

The Panama Canal has these huge gates. They close so the locks can be flooded or drained.

[image]

They're swing gates, so 3 questions come to mind:

- How are they water-tight at the hinges?
- How are they water-right at the middle, where the two gates meet?
- How are they water-tight at the bottom, where the gate drags across the floor?

**Edit:** Okay, they don't need to be perfectly water-tight. We can call them "decently sealed".

Comment: Well, for one thing, they aren't *perfectly* watertight; there's always some flow of water through the canal overall. The "leakage" just has to be low enough that the water source(s) at the high points of the canal can handle it, in addition to the water consumed in normal canal operations.

Comment: In this specific - I don't know. But a couple of ideas for how it *could* be done: At the bottom, you don't seal the bottom of the gate to the floor, you have a slight vertical lip at the bottom that the gate closes onto; a rubber seal between the two would help with water-tightness. At the middle, you have one gate which closes slightly before the other, which then overlaps it a little; rubber seal between the two. The hinges is harder due to the direction the gate is moving, but you're probably looking at the lip idea again.

Comment: The gates do leak, but not enough for it to matter. The basic design is arranged so that the water pressure on the gates creates a seal against some other part of the structure. The total water volume in each lock is about 26 million gallons, and the lock can be filled or emptied in about 10 minutes, so "leaks" of a few hundred gallons per minute are insignificant.